# Charts for .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, charts, visual-studio-2019

Is there an (easy) way to include Charts in to .NET CORE 5 like it is in the .NET Framework? (Drag and drop from the toolbox).

I tried several packages each one of them adding nothing to the toolbox, and most searches refer me to https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/ which changes nothing either.

The reason I ask is because I want to move from the .NET Framework to .NET Core but I constantly run in to the issue that .NET Core is lacking features that are basic in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Maybe consider switchting to Visual Studio 2022, designer support is still WIP here the latest blog post about the state - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/state-of-the-windows-forms-designer-for-net-applications/ - tough, I don't know if visual studio version actually makes a difference, just something you could give a try 
visual studio instances can be installed parallel, so no need to remove 2019

Comment: @RandRandom decided to just use the .NET Framework instead, might becomming outdated but atleast it works.

Comment: Does [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1e75392-ea81-4fd7-bfb8-6f4022f0c7ee/chart-control-with-net5?forum=csharpgeneral) can help you?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT i tried it, doesn't seem to work :/